# SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM Table WHERE Column1 has duplicates

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to show all the rows of the table where col1 has duplicates.

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |    0 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    2 |    0 |    0 |
|    3 |    0 |    0 |
|    3 |    1 |    1 |
|    4 |    0 |    0 |
+------+------+------+
```

The results should be:

```
+------+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | col3 |
+------+------+------+
|    1 |    0 |    0 |
|    1 |    1 |    1 |
|    3 |    0 |    0 |
|    3 |    1 |    1 |
+------+------+------+
```

I've tried some queries with no luck, so here I am asking for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the name of the table is T5 then use this:

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM T5
WHERE COL1 IN
(
    SELECT COL1
    FROM T5
    GROUP BY COL1
    HAVING COUNT(COL1)>=2
)
```

I checked and the above should not use any nonstandard SQL.  I am assuming that is the case for the others.

Comment: What is this about?: *"This should not use any nonstandard SQL."* All other provided answers are standard SQL, too.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense; I am editing the answer to mention this.

Answer (score 6):

Depending on your version of sql server you can use:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from
(
  select col1, col2, col3,
    count(col1) over(partition by col1) cnt
  from yourtable
) src
where cnt > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aa15/3)

Answer (score 3):

```
select t.col1, t.col2, t.col3
from mytable t join (select col1 
                     from mytable 
                     group by col1 
                     having count(*) > 1) t2
  on t.col1 = t2.col1
```

Answer (score 3):

Let me add one more variant solution. If you have a `pk` column that has a `UNIQUE` or `PRIMARY KEY` constraint, you can use:

```
select col1, col2, col3
from <yourTable> t1
where exists
  (select *
   from <yourTable> t2
   where t2.col1 = t1.col1
     and t2.pk <> t1.pk
  ) ;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select col1, col2, col3
from <yourTable> t1
where exists
  (select null
   from <yourTable> t2
   where t2.col1 = t1.col1
   group by t2.col1
   having count(*) > 1)
```

[sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5aa15/8)

Answer (score 1):

Guess I am too late.. but how about a left join...

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/401db/3)

Query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.col1, x.col2, x.col3 
FROM ab y
LEFT JOIN 
ab x
ON y.col1=x.col1 and ( y.col2<> x.col2
                    OR x.col3<>y.col3 )
where not (x.col3 is null)
and not (x.col2 is null)
;
```

Results:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
1       0   0
1       1   1
3       0   0
3       1   1
```

Comment: This is not exactly what is wanted: [SQL-Fiddle-2](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a2b7d/1)

Comment: Have you checked my fiddle (with different data but your code)? It doesn't show the 2 rows with `col1=1`